# C# RealTime track of logged time in app and send alert back to user

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.timers.timer

I need to build a Web Application using `C# ASPMVC` that keep track of the logged time and other actions that the user do in the application and send back an alert to client using `SignalR`.

My question is on the server side. For example:

User A login into the application. In that moment the application have to start tracking the time that the user has been connected. Exactly after 10 minutes the server will send some message to the user client (using `SignalR`).

At the same time while the user is connected, he might click on a specific button that the server must need to track the `TimeStamp` when the user clicked the button and start counting realtime server side the time elapsed. When this time elapsed reach 90 seconds I have to send a message back to client.

We can have for example 50 users and server side have to be watching all this timers and send the messages to every user.

How can this be solved server side, how to keep this times elapsed by user and trigger server side the events when the specific time rules are reached?

Comment: you probably need to take a look at  [HttpContext](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/httpcontext-class-in-Asp-Net/)

Comment: using [HttpContext](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/httpcontext-class-in-Asp-Net/) you can set a session time in your example (10 minutes) then you can trigger events whenever your session `Timeout`

Comment: HttpContext would be a good route. If you're set on going down the SignalR route, you'll need to setup an API to interact with a database of some sort to let SignalR know when the event was fired.

Comment: Does HttpContext let me create multiple like "stopwatch" so keep track of different times elapsed?

Comment: @VAAA You don't need to set a Stopwatch in the HttpContext since you can get the time Elapsed in the `Session` Property of the Current Httpcontext

Comment: How I can see session's timeout is not an option. A database mechanism can be an options as VAAA sugests. Another options is keep a list of object at application level and open a thread in a global .asax that do the verification logic...

Comment: @LeonardoNeninger exactly right, what about having async methods that are triggered for each stopwatch I need to track and each async method will  trigger to client the specific message whatever the time elapsed is reached. Because what I understand I can run as many times the same async method server side.